# How prove this $S_{n}\neq 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangulation

let $n$ is postive integer numbers,and let
$$S_{n}=\sin{1}-\sin{4}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\sin{(3n-2)}$$
show that
$$S_{n}\neq 0, \forall n\in N^{+}$$

My try: maybe this problem use
$$2\sin{x}\sin{y}=\cos{(x-y)}-\cos{(x+y)}$$

\begin{align*}2\sin{\dfrac{3}{2}}S_{n}&=2\sin{1}\sin{\dfrac{3}{2}}-2\sin{4}\sin{\dfrac{3}{2}}+\cdots+2(-1)^{n-1}\sin{(3n-2)}\sin{\dfrac{3}{2}}\\
&=\cos{\dfrac{1}{2}}-\cos{\dfrac{5}{2}}-\cos{\dfrac{5}{2}}+\cos{\dfrac{11}{2}}+\cdots
\end{align*}

I think  this is nice problem, Thank you

Comment: How about separating as  $$\sum_{0\le r\le n}\sin\{3(2m+1)-2\}$$ and $$\sum_{0\le r\le n}\sin\{3(2m)-2\}$$ using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro . We may need to consider the odd & the even case of $n$ as well

Comment: and Then ? Thank you

Comment: let me try after dinner

Comment: oh,I have wait you.

Comment: why  wolfram (http://goo.gl/wHbjsx) is saying : the sum $=-n\sin 2 ?$

Comment: How to by hand this ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, we know $\sin\theta=\Im~ e^{i\theta}$. Then
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sin(3k-2)=\Im~\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}e^{i(3k-2)}$$
The right hand side is actually the sum of geometric series with common ratio $-e^{3i}$. We have
$$S_n=\Im\frac{e^i(1-(-e^{3i})^n)}{1-(-e^{3i})}=\Im\frac{e^i-(-1)^ne^{i(3n+1)}}{1+e^{3i}}\neq0$$
The last step is a direct consequence of rationalize denominator of complex number.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
go with product to sum

then calculate sum of $n$th of sigma

at then end you have $6n-7=+-1+4k\pi$
so

$6k-8=4k\pi$ divide by 4 -->$k$ is not an integer

$6k-6=4k\pi$ divide by 4 -->$k$ is not an integer

so $s(n)$ is not zero

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Can you type it in LaTeX instead?